# More efficient SQL query structuring

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a `groups`, `users`, and `users_groups` table. The relationship between users and groups is many to many. Users can be allocated to multiple groups. I would like to run a query that gets a list of users who have ***at least*** 1 common group to a specific user ID.

1. How can I restructure this query to make it faster? I think it may have something to do with using GROUP BY?
2. How can I implement ordering such that the users with more common groups appear first?

   ```
   $user_id = $this->db->escape($user_id);
   $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(ug_user_id) 
               FROM users_groups
               INNER JOIN groups ON groups.group_id = users_groups.ug_group_id
               WHERE ug_group_id IN (
                   SELECT ug_group_id 
                       FROM users_groups 
                       WHERE ug_user_id = $user_id)
               LIMIT 50";
   $query = $this->db->query($sql);
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table with itself:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (g2.ug_user_id)
    FROM
        users_groups as g1
        JOIN
        users_groups as g2 
        ON g1.ug_group_id = g2.ug_group_id
            and g1.ug_user_id != g2.ug_user_id
    WHERE g1.ug_user_id = $user_id;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but that won't work because of the WHERE clause limiting the results to that specific user ID. I want a list of users who have groups in common to that user ID ;)

Comment: Thanks, will do some testing and let you know :)

Comment: Thanks it seemed to work! Do you know if it is possible to order by the number of common groups? No worries if you don't

Comment: for that you need a more compplicated query or a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use the following query to get a list ordered by the number of common groups:

```
SELECT ug_user_id, 
       COUNT(*) AS COMMONCOUNT
       FROM users_groups
       WHERE ug_group_id IN (
                    SELECT ug_group_id 
                    FROM users_groups 
                    WHERE ug_user_id = $user_id)
             AND ug_user_id <> $user_id
GROUP BY ug_user_id     
ORDER BY COMMONCOUNT DESC
```